# How to disable vi mode in fish?

Tags: fish

I enabled vi keybindings in fish-shell using `fish_vi_key_bindings` but now I'd like to go back to the default emacs-like settings. How do I escape?

Comment: Questions about using a shell interactively, as opposed to writing software to be interpreted by one, are generally a better fit for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: I see your point but that also goes for [the majority of questions about fish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish) and other shells...

Comment: fish is something of an odd case, inasmuch as its primary focus is on interactive use. We have a quite substantial pool of scripting-focused questions for bash, POSIX sh, ksh, zsh, etc -- and as someone who spends a lot of time in the bash and sh tags, I'm not shy about redirecting interactive-use questions elsewhere.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run `fish_default_key_bindings` to switch back to default (emacs) mode.

Answer (score 5):

It's remembered in the `fish_key_bindings` variable, so run

```
set -U fish_key_bindings fish_default_key_bindings
```

Comment: While this answer "works" it isn't recommended. It's the sort of implementation detail that is subject to change. Please use the `fish_default_key_bindings` function.